# DbContext has been disposed when using IQueryable<>

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a simple query in a repository like so:

```
   public List<MeetingVM> GetMeetingsInRadius(decimal latitude, decimal longitude, int miles, int dayOfWeek)
   {
       var point = DbGeography.FromText(string.Format("POINT ({0} {1})", longitude, latitude), 4326);
       using (MeetingContext db = new MeetingContext())
       {
           var results = (from a in db.Meetings
                          where a.Geography.Distance(point) * 0.000621371 <= miles
                          && a.DayOfWeek == (Meetings.Models.Enums.DayOfWeek)dayOfWeek
                          select a).Select(x => new MeetingVM
                          {
                              Address = x.Address,
                              CasoID = x.Address,
                              DayOfWeek = x.DayOfWeek,
                              distance = x.Geography.Distance(point) * 0.000621371,
                              Latitude = x.Latitude,
                              LocationName = x.LocationName,
                              Longitude = x.Longitude,
                              MeetingName = x.MeetingName,
                              MeetingType = x.MeetingType,
                              Options = x.Options,
                              Time = x.Time
                          }).OrderBy(x => x.Time).ToList();               
           return results;
       }           
   }
```

I tried changing it to return `IQueryable<>` instead of `List<>` , and I understand what that does, to become a Lazy query , and not execute until it is actually called.  But I do not understand why it throws exception

> "DbContext Has Been DIsposed"

when I change it to `IQueryable<>`, is my only option to make this work to set a private instance of DbContext in the repository and keep it open?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code sample above, you're calling `ToList()`, which gets your results from the database before the end of the `using` block disposes your context. So that should work fine.

If you return an `IQueryable`, then by the time you call `ToList()` or `FirstOrDefault()` or whatever and actually execute the query (perhaps much later in your code), the `using` block has long since disposed of your "MeetingContext", so you can't use it. Hence the exception.

Comment: That is what I thought... I have have to then look at pro's and con's of always keeping a DbContext open??

Comment: I just thought that the framework would keep that using block open until the query was finished